# Analogy of probabilistic independence with orthogonality

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Originally from the note: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2015/10/12/275a-notes-2-product-measures-and-independence/comment-page-2/#comment-682638.

Let ${X}$ be a random variable taking values in ${{\bf R}^n}$ with the Gaussian distribution, in the sense that

$\displaystyle \mathop{\bf P}( X \in S ) = \int_S \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{n/2}} e^{-|x|^2/2}\ dx$

(where ${|x|}$ denotes the Euclidean norm on ${{\bf R}^n}$), and let ${v_1,\dots,v_m}$ be vectors in ${{\bf R}^n}$. Show that the random variables ${X \cdot v_1, \dots, X \cdot v_m}$ (with ${\cdot}$ denoting the Euclidean inner product) are jointly independent if and only if the ${v_1,\dots,v_m}$ are pairwise orthogonal.

I don't quiet see how the Gaussian distribution of $X$ can be used to deduce information on the distribution of the random variables $X \cdot v_i$, any thought on either direction will be appreciated.

Comment: What are your thoughts? What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @RobertIsrael: Question edited.

Comment: Hint : in the one dimensional case if you have $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ Gaussian R.V. you have that $aX \sim \mathcal{N}(0,a^2)$

Comment: @Marco: Can you provide a more detailed explanation?

Comment: Independent means the covariance matrix is diagonal. If $V$ is a real and orthogonal matrix, then $V^{T}V$ is diagonal

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that the generalization of the hint i gave in the comment to random vectors is not so trivial:

A characterization of Gaussian R.V. is the [following](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Equivalent_definitions):

A Random vector $\mathbf{X} \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \Sigma)$  if its characteristic function is given by
$$
    \varphi_\mathbf{X}(\mathbf{u}) = \exp\Big( i\mathbf{u}^\mathrm{T}\mu - \tfrac{1}{2} \mathbf{u}^\mathrm{T}\Sigma \mathbf{u} \Big).
$$
In particular, in the case $\mathbf{X} \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \mathbf{\Sigma})$ we have
$$
 \varphi_\mathbf{X}(\mathbf{u})= \exp \Big( - \tfrac{1}{2} \mathbf{u}^\mathrm{T}\mathbf{\Sigma}\mathbf{u} \Big)
$$
Now consider the R.V. $(\mathbf{X} \cdot v_i)$
$$
\varphi_{(\mathbf{X} \cdot v_i)}(t):= \mathbb{E}  \left[\exp\big( i t (\mathbf{X} \cdot v_i)\big)\right]=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{\frac{n}{2}}}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \exp(i t (x \cdot v_i)) \exp(-\frac{1}{2}x^Tx)dx=\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2} t^2v_i^T v_i\right)
$$
So you have, by the characterization $(\mathbf{X} \cdot v_i) \sim \mathcal{N}(0,v_i^Tv_i)$ is a 1-dimensional Gaussian R.V.

Moreover  $(\mathbf{X} \cdot v_i, \mathbf{X} \cdot v_j ) \sim \mathcal{N}(0,(v_i,v_j)^T (v_i,v_j))$. Now it is  only a matter of comparing the density function of the two R.V. and noticing that
$$
f_{(\mathbf{X} \cdot v_i, \mathbf{X} \cdot v_j )}(x,y)=f_{\mathbf{X} \cdot v_i}(x) f_{\mathbf{X} \cdot v_j }(y)
$$
if and only if
$$
(v_i,v_j)^T (v_i,v_j)=v_i^Tv_i+v_j^Tv_j
$$
That actually means $v_i \cdot v_j=0$

Comment: Thank you so much for feedback, I need some time to digest your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let $Y = (X \cdot v_1, \dots, X \cdot v_m) = V^TX$, where $V$ is the matrix with columns $v_1, \dots, v_m$. Then since $X \sim N(0, I)$, $Y \sim N(0, V^TV)$. Thus the entries of $Y$ are independent if and only if the off-diagonal entries of $V^TV$ are all $0$.

Comment: I believe $V^{T}V$ only needs to be diagonal, not necessarily a multiple of the identity matrix.

Comment: @RezhaAdrianTanuharja Correct, we just need all pairwise covariance ls to be $0$.