# On probabilistic independence and orthogonality

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Originally asked in this post: [Analogy of probabilistic independence with orthogonality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4831324/analogy-of-probabilistic-independence-with-orthogonality), also available as Exercise $24$ of Tao's note: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2015/10/12/275a-notes-2-product-measures-and-independence/comment-page-2/#comment-682682.

Let ${X}$ be a random variable taking values in ${{\bf R}^n}$ with the Gaussian distribution, in the sense that

$\displaystyle \mathop{\bf P}( X \in S ) = \int_S \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{n/2}} e^{-|x|^2/2}\ dx$

(where ${|x|}$ denotes the Euclidean norm on ${{\bf R}^n})$, and let ${v_1,\dots,v_m}$ be vectors in ${{\bf R}^n}$. Show that the random variables ${X \cdot v_1, \dots, X \cdot v_m}$ (with ${\cdot}$ denoting the Euclidean inner product) are jointly independent if and only if the ${v_1,\dots,v_m}$ are pairwise orthogonal.

**Question**: Is there a more elementary approach to this problem by definition? e.g. Can we show directly that the random variables ${X \cdot v_1, \dots, X \cdot v_m}$ are s.t ${\bf P}(\bigwedge_{i=1}^m (X \cdot v_i \in S_i)) = \prod_{i=1}^m {\bf P}(X \cdot v_i \in S_i)$ for measurable subsets $S_i \subset {\bf R}$, if and only if the vectors ${v_1,\dots,v_m}$ are pairwise orthogonal?

Answer (score 1):

Note that we can omit any $v_i$ which are zero, since they're orthogonal to everything and $X\cdot 0=0$ the constant is independent of everything.

I'm going to use the following facts: An $n\times n$ matrix is orthogonal if its transpose is equal to its inverse. Such a matrix $U$ satisfies $\|Ux\|=\|x\|=\|U^{-1}x\|$ for all $x$ and $|\det(U)|=1$. Moreover, $UX$ has the same distribution as $X$ if $X\sim N(0,I_n)$ is the standard normal distribution in $n$ dimensions. We can directly deduce this from the pdf of $X$, since it depends only on $\|x\|$, which is preserved by $U$ (and $|\det|(U)|=1$ means the Jacobian of the change of variables $u=Uv$) is $1$.

If $v_1,\ldots,v_m$ are (non-zero and) orthogonal, then there exists an orthgonal $U$ such that $Uv_i=\|v_i\|e_i$ for $1\leqslant i\leqslant m$. Here $e_1,\ldots,e_n$ is the canonical basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then $Uv_1,\ldots,Uv_m$ have the same joint distribution as $\|v_1\|X_1,\ldots,\|v_m\|X_m$, which are independent (because the pdf of $X$ splits into products of pdfs of its coordinates). This shows that orthogonality gives independence.

On the other hand, if they're not orthogonal, we can reduce to the $n=2$ case. if $v_i,v_j$ are not orthogonal for some $i\neq j$, there exist numbers $a,b,c$ and a unitary transformation $U$ such that $Uv_i=ae_1$ and $Uv_j=be_1+ce_2$ and $a,b\neq 0$. These vectors have the same joint distribution as $aX_1$ and $bX_1+cX_2$. We can look at the joint marginal distribution of $X_1,X_2$ (by integrating out $X_3,\ldots, X_n$) and assume $n=2$. Since we know $aX_1,cX_2$ are independent, and hence uncorrelated, it suffices to observe that $aX_1,bX_1$ are not uncorrelated, so that $aX_1,bX_1+cX_2$ are not uncorrelated, and therefore not independent.

Comment: To make things a little more concrete, we can first try the model case where $v_1,\dots,v_m$ are the standard coordinate bases $e_1,\dots,e_m$, and set $m=n=2$. Professor Tao says that one can then compute the distributions of $X \cdot v_1, X \cdot v_2$ by direct computation (performing one-dimensional Gaussian integrals), and show that the product of these distributions agrees with the distribution of the joint random variable $X = (X \cdot v_1, X \cdot v_2)$.

Comment: I don't quiet get the part  of "compute the distribution of $X \cdot v_i$ by Gaussian integral". If $X$ is s.t$ \displaystyle \mathop{\bf P}( X \in S ) = \int_S \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{n/2}} e^{-|x|^2/2}\ dx$, how do we know the distribution ${\bf P}(X \cdot v_i \in S)$ of the dot product to be a Gaussian integral?

Comment: $$\mathbb{P}(UX\in S)=\mathbb{P}(X\in U^{-1}S)=\int_{U^{-1}S} f(x)dx \overset{y=Ux}{=}\int_Sf(U^{-1}y)|\det(U^{-1})|dy=\int_S f(y)dy=\int_S f(x)dx,$$ where $f$ is the $n$-dimensional $N(0,I)$ pdf. So $UX$,$X$ have the same distribution. $X\cdot v_i$ are the coordinates of $UX$, and the coordinates of a gaussian are gaussian.