# Sub-question on probabilistic independence and orthogonality

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory

This question is a sub-question of this post: [On probabilistic independence and orthogonality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4837594/on-probabilistic-independence-and-orthogonality).

Let ${X}$ be a random variable taking values in ${{\bf R}^n}$ with the Gaussian distribution, in the sense that

$\displaystyle \mathop{\bf P}( X \in S ) = \int_S \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{n/2}} e^{-|x|^2/2}\ dx$. (where ${|x|}$ denotes the Euclidean norm on ${{\bf R}^n})$, and let ${v_1,\dots,v_m}$ be vectors in ${{\bf R}^n}$. Show that the random variables ${X \cdot v_1, \dots, X \cdot v_m}$ (with ${\cdot}$ denoting the Euclidean inner product) are jointly independent if and only if the ${v_1,\dots,v_m}$ are pairwise orthogonal.

**Question**: By professor Tao's hint, one can first try the model case where $v_1,\dots,v_m$ are the standard coordinate bases $e_1,\dots,e_m$. Set $m=n=2$ to make things a little more concrete. One can compute the distributions of $X \cdot v_1, X \cdot v_2$ by direct computation (performing one-dimensional Gaussian integrals), and show that the product of these distributions agrees with the distribution of the joint random variable $Y = (X \cdot v_1, X \cdot v_2)$. I wonder how is this done? In particular, what does it mean to directly compute the distribution of $X \cdot v_i$ by Gaussian integral?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $V$ be the matrix whose rows are given by the $v_i$. Set $Y = VX$. Then $Y$ is a Gaussian vector with covariance $VV^T$. The thesis follows upon recalling that orthogonality is equivalent to independence for gaussians.

Comment: This is Exercise 24 of Tao’s note: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2015/10/12/275a-notes-2-product-measures-and-independence/comment-page-2/#comment-682682, and is placed before the notion of covariance is even introduced. So it should be accessible by the more elementary method mentioned in the hint above. Can you provide some explanation on that one?

Comment: We may take $n=m$ and $v_i$ to lie on the unit circle. Upon convincing yourself that the law of $X$ is rotationally invariant, $V$ being orthogonal then implies $VX$ and $X$ have the same law. (In particular, the law of $X$ is product measure.) Conversely, if $v_1$ and $v_2$ are not orthogonal, then $Y_1 = X\cdot v_1$ and $Y_2 = X\cdot v_2$ cannot be independent. Indeed, one has $$E[Y_1 Y_2] = \sum_{j=1}^n v_1^j v_2^j \neq 0 = E[Y_1]E[Y_2]$$

Comment: @Andrew: If $f_i(\omega) = X(\omega) \cdot v_i$ for all $1 \leq i \leq m$, it seems that ${\bf P}(X \cdot v_i \in S_i) = \int_{f_i^{-1}(S_i)} \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{n/2}} e^{-|x|^2/2}\ dx$, and ${\bf P}(\bigwedge_{i=1}^n (X \cdot v_i \in S_i)) = \int_{\bigcap_{i=1}^m f_i^{-1}(S_i)}  \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{n/2}} e^{-|x|^2/2}\ dx$, the original hint by professor Tao then seems to suggest that the latter integral is multiplicative over the intersection. Is this a feasible approach?

Comment: should be okay. (of course it is true, but this is not a priori known)

Comment: @Andrew: Since professor Tao explicitly pointed out that one can do it "by direct computation (say by performing one-dimensional Gaussian integrals in the model case $n = m = 2$), and show that the product of these distributions agrees with the distribution of the joint random variable", I just want to know if there's some properties of the Gaussian integral in my comment above to justify that a-priori computation?

Comment: @YuLynn yes it is the rotational invariance of the standard Gaussian measure

Comment: @Andrew: Sorry to bother again, but can you explain more on why $E[Y_1 Y_2] = \sum_{j=1}^n v_1^j v_2^j$?

Comment: One has $$E[Y_1Y_2] = E[(v_1^1X_1+\dots+v_1^nX_n)(v_2^1X_1+\dots+v_2^nX_n)]$$ Since $E[X_iX_j] = E[X_i]E[X_j] = 0$ if $i\neq j$, the cross terms vanish.

Comment: @Andrew: Thank you. But don't we need a separate justification for the fact that the components of $X$ are not correlated here?

Comment: It is given that the law of $X$ is product measure

Comment: @Andrew: And may I ask why does $EX_iEX_j = 0$ for $i \neq j$?

Comment: It's true even if $i=j$ since $E[X_i] = 0$ for all $i = 1,\dots,n$. The assumption $i\neq j$ is needed to write $E[X_iX_j] = E[X_i]E[X_j]$